# Divide a text file into number of small files

Tags: xml, perl

I have to break a text file—approx 600MB—to many smaller files, each with a unique name.

In the main file I have a tag (say `name`) which is repeated throughout the file. I have to make sets of six of those tags and place them in smaller text files.

Code: I am not able to generate multiple test files as my code is not proper.

```
$flag  = 0;
$flag1 = 0;

open( OUTPUT, "> Break$flag1.txt" ) or die "error open output file: $!\n";

foreach $iis_file ( <file_Name.txt> ) {

    #printf OUTPUT "Processing file: %s\n", $iis_file;

    open( INFILE, $iis_file ) or die "Can't open $file: $!";

    while ( <INFILE> ) {

        if ( /^<Name(.*)<\/Name>/i ) {

            $flag = $flag + 1;

            if ( $flag <= 6 ) {
                printf OUTPUT "<Name$1<\/Name>\n<\/Name>\n";
            }
        }
    }

    close INFILE;
}
```

Comment: On *Stack Overflow* we expect questions to include the code that you can't get to work. If you haven't written any code then you are asking in the wrong place.

Comment: From your code it looks like you're trying to process XML data. There are special modules for that. I suggest you take a look at [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig).

Comment: I suppose you get a better answer when you show (relevant portions of) your XML file.

Comment: There are some fundamental things wrong in your code. You never open a filehandle `INFILE`, and you attempt to read from a filename. Please [edit] and show your _real_ code.

Comment: Traversing XML files is a little tricky, particularly if you have to handle UTF-16 as well. You should use one of the XML libraries for that. Then you can do XML selections for your files.

Comment: @JamieWalton: Where did you get the idea that the OP is using UTF-16? What did I miss?!

Comment: @simbabque: `INFILE` is opened in the statement before the `while`, and I think `<file_Name.txt>` is supposed to be a glob.

Comment: @Borodin, I don't think you missed anything. I've just been caught with it.